# Wordpress pages on frontend and backend are loading very slow after adding thousands of images in its Media Gallery

Tags: wordpress, media

I have a Wordpress site, before it was working good all pages on backend and frontend was working well but when I add thousands of images in wordpress media gallery via **Add-this-Server Plugin**. The site has been too slow. Pages on backend and frontend working too slow and sometimes they show **500 internal server error**.

I looked around on internet for its solution and find some answers like increase **memory_limit** by writing this code(`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');`) to **wp-config.php** file.

But this also did not worked.

Please give me suggestion why it is happening.?
How can I remove this error and increase page loading speed.?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried logging out of admin to see if its just cause you're logged in?

Comment: Yes..I have tried after logging Out, still page loading speed is slow and sometime shows 500 Internal Server Error.